# Error using JQuery.post {use POST request} against Elastic Search

Tags: jquery, post, elasticsearch

Building a page to query Elastic Search (ES) and save the results to a file. I am trying to do this using JQuery.post to send the query and I'm receiving the error {"error": "Please use POST request"}

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        alert("ready!");

        $("#go").click(function(event) {

            alert("go!");

            /* get some values from elements on the page: */
            url=$("#host").val();
            alert(url);

            q=$("#q").val();
            alert(q);

            var posting = $.post( url, { data: q } );

            /* Put the results in a div */
            posting.done(function( data ) {
                alert(data);
                // var content = $( data ).find( '#content' );
                // $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );

                alert("done!");
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: can I get example values of #host and #q?  html 5 compliance can use attribute 'data-nameYouPick' and accessed as $("#host").data("nameYouPick"), and jQuery makes it backwards compatible.  this will also clear up valid json in 'q'

Comment: full code: http://jsfiddle.net/RetMp/116/

Comment: I imagine this is because $.post is an ajax request, and it suffers from the same origin policy restriction http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy, basically since you're hitting a url (localhost:9200) that is different from the url of the javascript you're executing (localhost), it fails.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
 .done(function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
 });
```

and also check the xhr status returning your $.post.also include the fail callback in your code

```
.fail(function() { alert("error"); })
```

The complete reference is [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: could you pls provide an exapmle url u sending ? pls check with firebug extension